# changes and deleting of a php file hosted locally

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, localhost

A PHP web application hosted locally on XAMPP does not accept changes or deletion of its files.
Whenever I make changes to a code in the file and run it , the browser displays the changes, but after a refresh, the changes are reversed.
i tried to delete the file or other files, but they come back when i refresh the pages.
I made changes to some codes in the files, and after saving them, the changes appeared just once in the browser. After refreshing the page again, all changes are reversed back to the old state. i tried deleting those particular files but it returns like it never happened.
Can someone help with a solution please? Thank you.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=caching+php+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: It would help if you could show us the relevant code you're struggling with, otherwise I got no idea, you might be editing php files, you might be editing template files created by some framework, no clue

Comment: Are you talking about you yourself modifying your code files, and you think something else is then overwriting those changes? Do you have some kind of sync service running on the server which is syncing them from another place?

Comment: The files are not mine. it coded by someone and the person is out of service.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a permissions problem in your local XAMPP.

Did you try these actions on a server? I remember that sometimes the act of deleting doesn't work in my local project but when I test it on the online server works correctly.

I hope that this info helps you.

Kind regards